# Command not found: pg_ctl on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, debian

PostgreSQL 9.4.8 Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

I just want an explanation of what is happening here. Why is this command not found? Nothing else.

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$ pg_ctl stop -m fast
pg_ctl: command not found
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$ sudo pg_ctl stop -m fast
[sudo] password for malikarumi: 
sudo: pg_ctl: command not found
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$ ls
clusterdb   initdb             pg_ctl          pg_restore      postmaster
createdb    oid2name           pg_dump         pg_standby      psql
createlang  pg_archivecleanup  pg_dumpall      pg_test_fsync   reindexdb
createuser  pg_basebackup      pg_isready      pg_test_timing  vacuumdb
dropdb      pgbench            pg_receivexlog  pg_upgrade      vacuumlo
droplang    pg_config          pg_recvlogical  pg_xlogdump
dropuser    pg_controldata     pg_resetxlog    postgres
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin$
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`pg_ctl` by design isn't in the path of the version of PostgreSQL Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) distributes. PostgreSQL is installed as a service in Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo service postgresql {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]
```

That command calls an `init.d` script which wraps around `pg_ctlcluster`. You can see that by opening `/etc/init.d/postgresql`. You can call `pg_ctlcluster` if you must. `pg_ctrlcluster` is a perl script that wraps around `pg_ctl` which isn't exposed (in the path) by design.

> **pg_ctrlcluster**: multiversion/cluster aware pg_ctl wrapper; this also supplies the correct configuration parameters to 'start', and makes sure that postgres really stops on 'stop'.

`pg_ctl` is technically distributed, but there is no reason to ever call it directly. To find it run

```
find /usr/lib/postgresql/ -name pg_ctl
```

You can call `pg_ctl` explicitly with the full path, however **don't.**

Also, going above and beyond and teaching you how to fish, you can always use `apropos` if you have these kind of questions later.

```
$ apropos pg_ctl
pg_ctl (1)           - initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server
pg_ctlcluster (1)    - start/stop/restart/reload a PostgreSQL cluster
```

Comment: Really like the apropos command. Never knew it existed! Thanks!

Comment: On later systems using "systemd", it's `sudo systemctl reload postgresql`